# Remove zeros from SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I delete the digit 0 in MySQL only for codes that have 7 digits?

Example:

- 0100396 (wipes 0 from the front)
- 010611 (will not be deleted)

Comment: Note that these are strings, and not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to *view* your data this way, use the following select:

```sql
SELECT IF(code REGEXP '^0[0-9]{6}$', RIGHT(code, 6), code) AS code
FROM yourTable;
```

If you want to *update* your table, then use this:

```sql
UPDATE yourTable
SET code = RIGHT(code, 6)
WHERE code REGEXP '^0[0-9]{6}$';
```

Note that this assumes that your `code` column is text, and not actually a number.  In the latter case, there are no leading zeroes.

Comment: I think you should  `LPAD` zeros to get back to length 6 after the `TRIM`, in case the initial code had several leading zeros, for example something like 0000123, but that is for OP to decide, we can only assume :s

Comment: @Pepper Actually it gets hairier than this.  What about an input like `1234567`.  Should the leading `1` be truncated?

Comment: Based on the initial question, I would assume not, but there are many things open to interpretation (are there 8+ character codes? with leading zeros? what should happens then?) And concerning my initial comment, I was just pointing it out for completeness :) (and yes, `RIGHT(...)` is cleaner than `LPAD(TRIM...)`, my bad :p )

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
update mytable 
set code=substring(code,2,7)
where length(code)=7 and substring(code,1,1)=0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a code, just put variable instead of hardcoded digits.

```
SELECT IF(LENGTH(0100396)=7, RIGHT(0100396, 6), 0100396);
```

Comment: This would not work as `LENGTH(0100396)` would first turn the number into a string ('100396') and take the length of that making the length 6 instead of 7. What you should do is to put values as strings instead of numbers.

Comment: That's why I wrote that it should be replaced with variables

Answer (score 0):

```
update DemoTable set Value=substr(Value,2)
```

to remove 1st value  from front

```
create table DemoTable (Value varchar(100));
insert into DemoTable values('83967364');
insert into DemoTable values('2345');
insert into DemoTable values('12345676');
select *from DemoTable;
select values FROM DemoTable
ORDER BY(CASE
WHEN LEN(values) > 6 THEN update DemoTable set Value=substr(Value,2)
ELSE values
END);
select *from DemoTable;
```